# Any way to get at OneNote custom tags via the API?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Is there any way to get at a OneNote page's custom (user-defined) tags via the API? (I'm aware they don't appear in the HTML content.)

(The Evernote API allows you to read (and set) custom tags, which makes it considerably more versatile.)

Answer (score 0):

sorry we don't have support for custom tags via the APIs yet. Full list of supported tags can be found at https://gist.github.com/nickbarnwell/c695fc4bb5b34d998622.

Please consider voting up for custom tags at [UserVoice](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis)

Comment: Thanks for your response, DipakBoyed. I see a glimmer of hope in your 'yet' ;) I've lodged a request for custom tags in UserVoice (it was earlier requested in the idea for 'API support for tags, including custom tags', but that was marked as completed on the basis that support for built-in tags only has been launched.)